# Templates with Facelets and calling action from template's component?

Tags: templates, jsf, servlets, facelets

I'm a newbie in JSF, facelet, richfaces... 
and I understood managed beans, methods called within JSF components
However, I wanted to use facelets template with the ui:composition, ui:define, like master pages in asp.net

But I have an action that's meant to be called in a masterpage component... and I keep having the same error :

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: #{connectionMB.logOut}: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /masterPage.html @134,65 action="#{connectionMB.logOut}": Method not found: ConnectionBean
```

because the component is on the template page masterPage.html :

```
<jsf:commandLink id="link" action="#{connectionMB.logOut}" >Log Out</jsf:commandLink>
```

and the user action comes from other html pages which begin with :

the pages are treated server side, apache mixes the masterPages elements with the content of other pages...
but how I am supposed to make an action called on a component's masterPage work for any pages ?

in my faces-config I tried lots of things :

```
<navigation-rule>
<from-view-id>/MySiteName/*</from-view-id>
<navigation-case>
        <from-action>#{connectionMB.logOut}</from-action>
```

or

```
<from-view-id>*</from-view-id>
```

or

```
<from-view-id>/masterPage.html</from-view-id>
```

none of this works...

if someone got a clue...
thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is (currently) not in the navigation cases. For them - you can totally omit the `<from-view-id>`.

The problem is that your `ConnectionBean` does not have a `public String logOut()` method (it can be `void` as well).

Answer (score 0):

ok that was entirely my fault. 
You can of course call a method from a master page without even specifying some navigation-rule. 
My project had some errors, and so didn't compile the last things I developed. that's all ...
thank you anyway !